# Transpose changes a date from 8th of January 2022 to 1st of August 2022

Tags: excel, vba

I transpose table 1 to table 2.

I encountered one issue regarding the date. From table 1, the date was **8th of January 2022**, but once I transpose the table, the date changed to **1st of August 2022**.

```vb
Sub ImportData()

   Dim Fname As String
   Dim Wbk As Workbook
   Dim Sht As Worksheet
   
   ' Select excel Sheet command
   Set Sht = ActiveSheet
   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*), *.xls*", , "select a File", , False)
   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
   Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
   
   ' Transpose Data
   Sht.Range("A1:F3").Value = Application.Transpose(Wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C6").Value)
   Wbk.Close False
   
End Sub
```

Table 1:

| Company | Item | Date | `8/1/2022` | 15/2/2022 | 25/3/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC LTD | Desktop | Cust demand | 6204 | 9600 | 19904 |
| ABC LTD | Desktop | Shipped qty | 6204 | 9600 | 19904 |

Table 2:

| Company | ABC LTD | ABC LTD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item | Desktop | Desktop |
| Date | Cust Demand | Shipped qty |
| **`1/8/2022`** | 6204 | 6204 |
| 15/2/2022 | 9600 | 9600 |
| 25/3/2022 | 19904 | 19904 |

I tried formatting the dates on both worksheets to the same format.

Comment: What is your local date format?  m/d/y, or d/m/y?  What format is applied to the source cells which have dates?

Comment: Is the original data dates or does it just look like a date? if in some other cell you type: =D1+1 does it give you the next day, or an error?

Comment: Are you aware that you are telling us that you're transposing from 1 to 2 while your code is transposing from 2 to 1? Or did you accidentally switch the ranges? You are writing (transposing) to the left side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely stems from the fact that VBA date handling is US Centric (`MDY`), even though your regional settings are `DMY`.

One workaround is to use the `FormulaLocal` property of the `Range` object rather than the `.Value` property.

Another workaround is to just not use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`, but rather use a custom function, as described by @VBasic2008

`WorksheetFunction.Transpose` has another limitation if the size of the range to be transposed is greater than `2^16-1`, so I frequently try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose Range Values

- Someone once told me that transpose has issues with dates. I never experienced this on my own but I usually write a function or sub for such a task.
- Try the following method and possibly prove that the previous is true and share some feedback.
- In your sub, you can use it in the following way:

  ```
  TransposeRange Wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C6"), Sht.Range("A1")
  ```
- BTW your sub works correctly on my end.

**The Method**

```vb
Sub TransposeRange( _
        ByVal SourceRange As Range, _
        ByVal FirstDestinationCell As Range) _
    
    Dim sData(), srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    With SourceRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        scCount = .Columns.Count
        If srCount * scCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1).Value = .Value
        Else
            sData = .Value
        End If
    End With
        
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To scCount, 1 To srCount)
        
    Dim sr As Long, sc As Long
        
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            dData(sc, sr) = sData(sr, sc)
        Next sc
    Next sr
    
    FirstDestinationCell.Resize(scCount, srCount).Value = dData
    
End Sub
```